# Runnin mysql, mariadb sql files from command line and keeping the output in stdout

Tags: mysql

## Problem

> no output to stdout when running queries from command
>
> - source command
> - drop, create, insert into ...

- when connecting to mysql first, and then use `source file.sql`. The command runs and shows output in stdout for every sql, which is great and is what I want through running through shell commmands.
- I'm using `mariadb`. I want to do the same but with `sudo mysql dbname -e "source file.sql"` or `sudo mysql dbname < file.sql`

  - Also with `sudo mysql dbname -e "DROP TABLE some;"` (normal query that is not a select)

I tried many things. Couldn't find a way.

**Is it possible? How?** Thank you a lot

(I want to use the command version rather than connect for speed purposes and command history)

Comment: `cat file.sql | sudo mysql dbname`

Comment: BTW: Why do you (think you need) `sudo` ?

Comment: cat file.sql | sudo mysql dbname => same thing as the two way i provided. It run silently. Just tried it

Comment: @Luuk sudo generally it's not a good practice, because if you make a mistake on the db name, dangerous damage can happen. In my case it didn't matter dev env. no dbs. I use it because of `/*!50013 DEFINER=\`user\`@\`%\` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */ ` security which require privileges. i have the user with all privileges on the db. But i still get a SET USER privilege error or something. So instead of seeing about changing user privileges i just went with sudo (root user on macos or linux)

Comment: So, you are _misusing_ sudo, because you do not want to specify the DEFINER in your code... 

Comment: No, im using sudo beccause i don't want to set privileges in order to restore a db. The DEFINER I'm setting. 
When you get that error two options. You remove the definer, or you fix priviligges. i did fix priviliges with sudo. For your curiosity, here is the error `Access Denied: you need (at least one of) the SET USER privilege(s) for this operation` (of course none of that is related to my question). the error suggesting User setting privileges. Sudo is reasonable for me. doesn't make for my user to have such a privilege.

Comment: Otherwise if it was in a prod env. I would take the normal user with db privileges and add the set user privileges whatever those are and play it safe. (basically my normal user, with all policies and i just give that one) Otherwise, i think the same error in the past was asking for super user privileges. I think the error changed cross versions or in mariadb (I'm using mariadb). The super user => sudo seems it just asking for it. in prod better be safe. and run with a user that has the privileges set as they should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148392/discussion-between-mohamed-allal-and-luuk).